# How to use function pointer between 2 classes

Tags: c++

> i have 2 classes say "Class A" and "Class B". i tried to declare the function pointer prototype in "Class A" and use it in "Class B", but failed. Please look in to my sample code and assist me how to make it success.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>   

using namespace std;
class A
{
  public:
    int (*funcPtr)(int,int);
    void PointerTesting(int (*funcPtr)(int,int))
    {               
       //i need to get B::test as an function pointer argument
    }

 };

 class B
 {
    public:
      int test(int a,int b)
      {
        return a+b;
      }
  };

  int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
  { 
    int (A::*fptr) (char*) = &B::test;  

    getchar();
    return 0; 
  }
```

Comment: Please don't spam with unrelated language tags.

Comment: Ask C ++ question in right place

Comment: As for your problem, non-static member function are *not* equal to static or global or namespace functions. A non-static member function needs an *object* to be called on. I suggest you look up [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Read this [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 2):

### Recommendation: Use < functional >, std::function and std::bind

```
#include <iostream>   
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
class A {
public:
    using FnPtr = std::function<int(int, int)>;

    void PointerTesting(const FnPtr& fn) {               
        //i need to get B::test as an function pointer argument

        // Example: Print 1 and 2's sum.
        int result = fn(1, 2);
        std::cout << "Result: " << result << std::endl;
    }
};

class B {
public:
    int test(int a,int b) {
        return (a+b);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 
    A a;
    B b;
    A::FnPtr ptr = std::bind(&B::test, b, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);

    a.PointerTesting(ptr);

    getchar();
    return 0; 
}
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

Comment: i am getting this error while compilation,error C2873: 'FnPtr' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration ,error C2039: 'function' : is not a member of 'std' , error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int , error C3861: 'fn': identifier not found

Comment: Are you including <functional>? Which cpp Version do you use?

Comment: yes i included <functional>,i am using visual studio 2008

Comment: Post detailed error messages (entire compile log containing errors and warnings).

Comment: error C2873: 'FnPtr' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration                                           error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '='                                                          error C2039: 'function' : is not a member of 'std'                                                     error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'                                                      error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Comment: error in using FnPtr declaration itself as per compiled results

Comment: Hm... I see... The compiler is really old. Is there a reason to not use one of the more recent Visual Studio Community versions?

Comment: i am having this version as of now (2008 version)

Comment: are you using C# project? or C++ project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145363/discussion-between-mabvt-and-shivcena).